# menu is not shown unless group activity is focussed

Tags: android

menu option  not visible on menu btn click unless it is focussed.

```
       @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(" in menu");     
    new MenuInflater(this.getParent()).inflate(R.menu.sample, menu);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

try reading this blog post: http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html.

If the menu doesn't come up in the sub-activities of your ActivityGroup simply override the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected methods in your ActivityGroup to call the corresponding method of your current sub-activity.

Here is what you need to add in your ActivityGroup class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return this.getCurrentActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return this.getCurrentActivity().onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

That's it. Now implement these methods in each of your sub-activities to your liking and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

log in onKeyDown method on every your group activity when press menu
then you can trace what's going on

there must be a activity receive keypress event, you should take a look
and you can see this  [article](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

parent ActivityGroup:

```
  @Overridepublic boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      Log.d(TAG, "in parent");
  menu.clear();
  return getCurrentActivity().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}

---

child ActivityGroup:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_gionew, menu);
    Log.d(TAG, "in childA");
    return true;
}
```

---

Comment: i have implented onkeydown method in every activity with a print statement inside it..but clicking menu btn doesnt respond any print satement

Comment: Thanx for replying and i implemented abv code but it still not working. but i made obsvertion ,wen i change tab and come back to searchresult activity and click on menu btn then it works fine.it seems like my tabbar activity shud be on top..

Comment: If you override onKeyDown() in you activity in which your menu, then write code to listen Menu key as "if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) " and call your menu. It will work.